# Node.js array slice operation is "thread safe"?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I have a simple websocket chat server which handles multi clients. I use an array to keep track of all clients and slice the array when a client closes the connection.

I was wondering when multiple clients close connections at about the same time, will slicing the array cause problem.

Here is the code segment:

```
var clients = []; 
var wsServer = new webSocketServer ({
    httpServer: httpserver
});

wsServer.on('request', function(request) {
    var connection = request.accept(null, request.origin);
    var index = clients.push(connection) - 1;

....

connection.on('close', function(connection) {
    for (var i=0; i<clients.length; i++) 
        if (i != index) clients[i].sendUTF('Some client has left the chat!');

    //At this point some other clients may have disconnected and the above 
    //for-loop may be running for another connection.

   clients.splice(index, 1);

   //After the array has been sliced, will the for-loop for other 
   //connection(s) fail?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript is single threaded, so yes, `Array.splice` is thread safe.

Async callbacks can only enter the call stack, when the call stack is empty. So, if there is an `Array.splice` on the call stack, the other callback containing an `Array.splice` will have to wait until the first one is done.

```
const arr = [1,2,3,4];
request('http://foo.com', (err, res, body) => {
   arr.splice(0, 1)
});

request('http://bar.com', (err, res, body) => {
   arr.splice(0, 1)
});
```

Consider the snippet above. In case those requests finish at the same time (just imagine it for the sake of argument). Then one callback, either `foo.com` or `bar.com` will enter the call stack. **All** the synchronous code inside that callback will be executed (The async call will be executed, but not the callback), and the callback from the other request, **cannot be processed until the call stack is empty**. So  `foo.com` and `bar.com` callback can't be processed at the same time.

**Javascript is single threaded, it has one call stack, so it can only do one thing a time.**

Comment: One of the things that makes Node.js development super easy is having the security of knowing that everything in a synchronous block is "thread safe", and being able to explicitly determine the control flow of anything asynchronous using callbacks (or more often promises nowadays).

Comment: Indeed, it gives you a peace of mind, knowing that you don't have to worry about that nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I understand it now and which lead me to discover a bug in the code (not related to this question)  :)

Comment: You're welcome. I recommend watching this video which explains this fairly well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ